# Finding id of shape dragged onto screen in Visio using VBA macro

Tags: vba, shapes, visio

I currently have a program in Visio that when a specific shape in my custom stencil is dragged onto the screen, a user form comes up and asks the user a question with a combo box used for the user to select an answer.

Based on the answer selected, the shape data should change for that object.

The problem that I am facing is that I am not sure how to target the ID of the shape automatically to then change its shape data. Since multiple of these shapes may be placed, I can not manually write a new piece of code for every ID.

[Image: Shapesheet of the shape running the macro on drop. "Form" is the user form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pusle.jpg)

[Image: Userform macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCPCA.jpg)

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this problem.

Thank you

Comment: How do you know when to open the userform? In other words, what event are you handling? Also, some code would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Zev, I have edited my post to show that the user form macro runs when the shape is dropped onto the screen. (EventDrop). I have also attached my current code.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if the `CALLTHIS` ShapeSheet function might be more useful here as it passes a reference to the calling shape.  So, for example, in the `EventDrop` cell add this formula:

```
CALLTHIS("ThisDocument.OnMyShapeDrop","Drawing001")
```

and then add this backing code:

```
Public Sub OnMyShapeDrop(shp As Visio.Shape)
    MsgBox "Shape dropped - ID = " & shp.ID, vbOKOnly, "Shape Dropped"
End Sub
```

Note, that I've put the code in the `ThisDocument` class, but it can live in any accessable module.  Also note the project name (Drawing001) which will likely be the file name without the extension.

Comment: For others like me finding this answer helpful, [this link](http://guides.wmlcloud.com/office/Microsoft-Visio-2010---Introducing-Automation-and-VBA-Code-(part-3)---Calling-VBA-Code-from-a-SmartShape-.aspx) provides some additional example material.